# Collapse table list

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a list of the process where each row has a link called "Collapse" which if clicked should open a "container area", where I can put some other stuff inside.

What I've done so far is this:

[image]

But as you can see, the container will have the same size as the first column "# ".

How could I avoid this? Or is there a better way to do this using divs or whatever?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th class="th-lg"><a>#</a></th>
        <th class="th-lg"><a>Status</a></th>
        <th class="th-lg"><a>ID</a></th>
        <th class="th-lg"><a>Process Name</a></th>
        <th class="th-lg"><a>Actions</a></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Active</button></td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>foobarbaz</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Success</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Success</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#tr_a" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="tr_a">
                <span>Collapse</span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_a" class="collapse">
        <td>container</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Down</button></td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>foobarbaz</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Success</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Success</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#tr_b" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="tr_b">
                <span>Collapse</span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_b" class="collapse">
        <td>container</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: UX protip: Don't label a button that *expands* something with "collapse". Use "Show more" or "expand" or something along those lines.

Comment: That was just a naming layout, nothing to do with the whole application.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`rowspan`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#adef-rowspan) attribute to make your container span multiple columns:

```
<tr id="tr_b" class="collapse">
    <td colspan="6">container</td>
</tr>
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="th-lg"><a>#</a></th>
        <th class="th-lg"><a>Status</a></th>
        <th class="th-lg"><a>ID</a></th>
        <th class="th-lg"><a>Process Name</a></th>
        <th class="th-lg"><a>Actions</a></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Active</button></td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>foobarbaz</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Success</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Success</button></td>
        <td>
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#tr_a" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="tr_a"> <span>Collapse</span> </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_a" class="collapse">
        <td colspan="6">container</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

(Red borders are for visualization only)

Answer (score 0):

You can try add colspan attribute with value 6 which represent you want to merge 6 columns into 1

```
<td colspan="6">container</td>
```

Thanks..